# How do I specify size of a dxf in openscad?

Tags: openscad

I am new to openscad and trying to make a 3d model from a dxf file. I want to specify its size as 130x130. I've been able to get as far as the code below but it still does not assert the size I want:

```
linear_extrude(height = 5, center = true, convexity = 10) import (file="bahtinov.dxf");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dxf_dim()`: create a further layer in your dxf, e.g. "dimensions", draw a horizontal and a vertical dimension line with the max. width resp. the max. height as described in [Documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#Getting_input), as identifier e.g. "TotalWidth" and "TotalHeight", here my test-drawing as example:

[image: dimension line with identifier]

get the values with:

```
tw = dxf_dim(file="bahtinov.dxf", name="TotalWidth", layer="dimensions", scale=1);
th = dxf_dim(file="bahtinov.dxf", name="TotalHeight", layer="dimensions", scale=1);
```

scale the part:

```
scale([130/tw,130/th,1]) linear_extrude(height = 5, center = true) import(file="bahtinov.dxf", layer="layerName", scale=1);
```

Comment: when I read the documentation from your link, I still can't find how to actually create this TotalWidth value for example, it cryptically says: In the drawing, create a dimension that does not show the dimension value, but an identifier.
Could you incorporate this first step in your answer to make it comprehensive? 
(I assume there is a step missing since I get: WARNING: Can't find dimension 'TotalWidth' in 'bahtinov.dxf', layer 'dimensions'!)

Comment: @Sebastian i added a screenshot of the cad-drawing to my answer. As i don't have 'bathinov.dxf', i created an own 'get_input.dxf' and 'get_input.scad'. you can download them from here 
https://app.box.com/s/m64cn5yk1wb3mb4i3a5ofwwk3s5yji7k ,
you can ignore the warnings in openscad-console of openscad 2015

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I misunderstood the procedure, if I am correct now: you add these dimensions with another program in the dfx. I was looking for a solution inside openscad, given any dfx, when I stumbled on this thread. But I will open my own question then if I don't find another solutions. Thanks!

Comment: correct: use simply the cad-program  you use to generate the dxf-drawing

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using resize() on the imported DXF:

```
linear_extrude(height = 5, center = true, convexity = 10) resize([130,130]) import (file="bahtinov.dxf");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but you can scale it afterwards.

```
scaling_factor=0.5;
scale([scaling_factor,scaling_factor,1])
linear_extrude(height = 5, center = true, convexity = 10) import (file="bahtinov.dxf");
```